# Arcpy Report all MXDs using specified Layer

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

I have a code I'm working on using python 2.7 and the arcpy plugin.
The user will plug in a layer file and a root directory to search. 
The code will os.walk the directory and find every .MXD file. It will then search each .MXD file for the specified .SHP file. If an .MXD reports using the .SHP requested, it will log that .MXD file.

where lyr = E1.get() and is the .shp file being searched for.

```
lyr = E1.get()    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for name in files:
                    basename, extension = os.path.splitext(name)
                    if extension == '.mxd':
                        fullPath = os.path.join(root,name)
                        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullPath)
                        DataList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
                        for item in DataList:
                            if item == lyr:
                                LOG_ME = mxd
                                l.info(LOG_ME)
                            else:
                                pass
                    else:
                        pass
```

The logfile is created when the program runs, but never populates any data. I receive no errors, even in a directory I know contains .MXDs that use the specified .SHP
I've also tried

```
for item in DataList:
    if lyr in item:
        log
```

and

```
if lyr in DataList:
    log
```

any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: The above log method will result in a map-object (same issue as fixed below).To log it correctly, I changed it too `l.info(basename)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem may be in your comparison

```js
if item == lyr:
```

Note that arcpy.mapping.ListLayers returns a list of layer objects, not a list of layer names.

Try changing your comparison to

```js
if item.name == lyr:
```

Good luck!

Tom

Comment: Worked brilliantly, though with the caveat that the file extension is excluded from the original search parameter. I'm not sure why, but a useful note for anyone else pursuing this type of code.